# DataList - how to get the ClientID for another control other than the one your on?

Tags: asp.net, datalist

Have a datalist with several textboxes, a series of "Time1" and "Time2"
So Im trying to attach a javascript onblur event to each one, and pass the client id values to a function, but how to reference the clientid of another control than the one your editing?

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="txtTimeFrameFrom" onblur='javascript:updateTimeFrame(val1, val2,val3);'  style="width:50px;font-size:x-small;"  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TimeFrameFrom")%>'></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="txtTimeFrameTo" onblur='javascript:updateTimeFrame(val1, val2,val3);'  style="width:50px;font-size:x-small;"  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TimeFrameTo")%>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Where:

```
val1 = numeric value from dataset
val2 = client id of txtTimeFrameFrom
val3 = client id of txtTimeFrameTo
```

How can I get the client id in each case, while within the DataList?  Is there an easier way?

Comment: You could use [jQuery Parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), and search the sibling textboxes. Without seeing the generated html code, I could not say the exact answer.

Comment: I think I have a solution using the ItemDatabound event to handle this in the codebehind.  Ill update after I have it working